# Setting authorization for Web service call from .bat file

Tags: java, web-services, batch-file, soap

I am trying to call a web service from a .bat file. How can I set username and password for the service call?

I am trying this:

```
start iexplore https://hostname:port/myapplication/services/service/process?source=srcA
```

Answer (score 0):

Is okay using IE? We need to do it with wsh. Here is all information we need to do it in `vbs` [Matias Balsløw, Foxtrot Alliance](https://support.foxtrotalliance.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023770832-How-To-Automate-IE-With-VBScript)

Example,

```vb
set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IE

.Visible = True

.Navigate "https://hostname:port/myapplication/services/service/process?source=srcA"

Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
  'Do nothing, wait for the browser to load.
Loop

Do While .Document.ReadyState <> "complete"
    'Do nothing, wait for the VBScript to load the document of the website.
Loop    

'We have to change this two lines
.Document.getElementsByName("q").Item(0).Value = "Stackoverflow"
.Document.getElementsByName("btnK").Item(0).Click

End With
```

We can execute it with (in the command prompt),

`cscript /nologo [name.vbs]`